# Toggle Class or addClass/removeClass to multiple divs with jquery or vanilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items and when clicked on an item need to add a class name to parent div, and other inside divs, then when click other item, need to be removed the classes.

```
<ul class="items">
    <div class="item box active">
       <div class="info active2">hello world</div>
     </div>
     <div class="item box">
        <div class="info">hello world</div>
     </div>
 </ul>
```

**script**

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    $('.box.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

this one add class only the `box` class, but `"info"` has `active2`

i would like this

```
$('.box').click(function () {
        $('.box.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.info.active2').removeClass('active2');
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        $('.info').addClass('active2'); 
    });
```

doesn't work, how can i solve this?
thanks

Comment: Could you show the entire relevant HTML. Your current code uses a lot of classes not present in your HTML. I would also ask that you use the snippet function here so that your example can be tested here.

Comment: hi @Achtung  thanks for answer, i missed the box class in item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('.box').click(function () {
        $('.box.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.info.active2').removeClass('active2');
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        $(this).children('.info').addClass('active2'); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items">
    <div class="item box active">
       <div class="info active2">hello world</div>
     </div>
     <div class="item box">
        <div class="info">hello world</div>
     </div>
 </ul>
```